# trouble with a range of numbers python

Tags: python

I need help with a function which can't decide how to include a range of numbers.
This is my function and I don't know why doesn't work correctly with the numbers in a range.

```
def word_score(word):
    """ (str) -> int
Return the point value the word earns.

Word length: < 3: 0 points
             3-6: 1 point per character for all characters in word
             7-9: 2 points per character for all characters in word
             10+: 3 points per character for all characters in word

>>> word_score('DRUDGERY')
16
"""
if len(word) < 3:
    return 0
elif len(word) == range(3, 6) :
    return len(word)
elif len(word) == range(7, 9):
    return len(word)* 2
elif len(word) >= 10:
    return len(word) * 3



return word_score
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range` does not include last value. For example, `range(0,3)` will produce only 0,1 and 2, but NOT 3.

Also you should check whether your `len(word)` is in range and not if it's equal to range, for `len(word)` is a string and range is... range so it will always produce `False`.

Your code should look like:

```
if len(word) < 3:
    return 0
elif len(word) in range(3, 7) :
    return len(word)
elif len(word) in range(7, 10):
    return len(word)* 2
elif len(word) >= 10:
    return len(word) * 3
```

if you want to use range.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `in` operator , here is your fault:

```
num = 4
num == range(3, 6) # false
# it will be true if num = [3, 4, 5]
num in range(3, 6) # true
# it means num is 3 or 4 or 5
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with that code isn't checking if the number is within a certain **range**, you're checking if your number is equal to a range of numbers between the two that you offered. Range isn't for the usage you are describing, it is for generating ranges to iterate over. Instead, use `if number >= 3 and number >= 6:
    print ("Within range")`

You would not want to use "in" as this checks every single number in the set if it is equal to the one that you gave it, this is very inefficient and operates in **(O)n** time.